# Gradle buildSrc and buildscript

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We have a Gradle build that includes a `buildSrc` with some custom plugins. Those plugins apply yet other plugins. For example, our plugin applies `com.android.tools.build:gradle`. For annotation processing that library needs to be on Gradle's classpath during compilation. So, putting this in our main `build.gradle` works:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gToolsVersion"
    }
}
```

However, that means that for a user to apply this plugin they must (1) apply our plugin and (2) add that `buildscript` boilerplate. It seems like that shouldn't be necessary.  We can also add a `project.buildscript` block inside our plugin but that too seems unnecessary and, due to this bug is problematic: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html?utm_source=android-studio#known_issues.

I added the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` dependency to `buildSrc/build.gradle` as a `runtime` dependency. It seems like that should work: I thought that tells Gradle that in order to run my plugin that library (and its dependencies) need to be on the classpath. However, `gradle buildEnvironment` (and the fact that our build fails) makes it clear that's not the case.

So, questions:

1. What's the difference between a `runtime` dependency specified in `buildSrc/build.gradle` and a `classpath` dependency specified in a `buildscript` block in a regular build.gradle?
2. How can I arrange things so that users can apply the plugin from `buildSrc` and *not* have to also add the `buildscript` block to their `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 3):

I got a slightly different problem and found an acceptable solution that might help with for your second question: I wanted to apply the same repositories in the `buildSrc/build.gradle` and twice in the root `build.gradle`.

`repositories.gradle` in the project root:

```
repositories {
    if (project.hasProperty('nexus')) {
        maven {
            url 'http://localhost:8081/repository/JCenter/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://localhost:8081/repository/Maven_Google/'
        }
    } else {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

ext {
    androidGradleBuildToolsDependency = 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
}
```

`buildSrc/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: '../repositories.gradle'
}

allprojects {
    apply from: '../repositories.gradle'
}

dependencies {
    // androidGradleBuildToolsDependency is defined in repositories.gradle
    implementation androidGradleBuildToolsDependency
}
```

Root `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
}

allprojects {
    // this line will also be executed from the build.gradles in subprojects, so the working
    // directory isn't always the same, so we use the absolute path here
    apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/repositories.gradle"
}
```

Note that you do not need the `classpath` dependency inside the `buildscript` block of the root `build.gradle` as you normally would. The `implementation` dependency in the `repositories.gradle` seems to auto apply it.

My solution probably doesn't work when the `build.gradle`s are supplied via a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this while digging into a tangential problem.

I've been successfully using `buildSrc/build.gradle` as the place to define dependencies that would normally belong in the root-project's buildscript classpath for a few of my projects.

You can see a working example here: https://github.com/episode6/chop/blob/develop/buildSrc/build.gradle

I used to use `compile` dependencie but just switched to `runtimeClasspath` which feels more appropriate and also works. I don't think your `classpath` dependencies were working because they would be on the classpath of the `buildSrc` project, but not compiled into or run along side it.

If you decide to go this route, you may run into the problem I was just digging into which only came up because of this approach.

When I tried this approach with the `dokka` plugin, I got the following error

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-fatjar:0.9.17 because no repositories are defined
```

I was able to workaround this by adding jcenter() to the root project's buildscript repositories: https://github.com/episode6/chop/blob/develop/build.gradle#L2